# Twilio video track attach not showing video of remote participant

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

Remote video not attaching using trackSubscribed and publication.isSubscribed returning false when i reload the browser and when i attach track using browser console the video is shown as expected. Twilio-video version 2.13.1

Comment: Can you share your code around the trackSubscribed event?

Comment: @philnash you can check code here https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/1453